# How to prevent repeating long rvalue

Tags: c++, coding-style, rvalue

```
int main() {
    int x = 1, y = 2, z = 3, w = 4;
#define formula x + y * z % w
    x++;
    do_something1(formula);
    y++;
    do_something2(formula);
    z++;
    do_something3(formula);
    w++;
    do_something4(formula);
#undef formula
    return 0;
}
```

I'm currently using `#define` to prevent repeating long rvalue. Is there any better alternative way to do this?

Comment: Do you know what a function is?   If so, why not write a function that does the calculation required of the formula?

Comment: `int formula(int x,int y, int z, int w) { return x+y*z%w; }`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [lambda](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) expression:

```
int main() {
    int x = 1, y = 2, z = 3, w = 4;
    auto formula = [&] { return x + y * z % w; };
    x++;
    do_something1(formula());
    y++;
    do_something2(formula());
    z++;
    do_something3(formula());
    w++;
    do_something4(formula());
    return 0;
}
```